# Node.js : render html content express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to render content html to view in node js but it not format html standard. I use node js MVC

My controller:

```
exports.Formhtml = function(request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    response.setHeader('Content-Length', body.length);        
    response.pageInfo = {};
    response.pageInfo.content = '<h1>this is html format tag h1</h1>';
    response.pageInfo.title = 'formhtml';
    response.render('home/Formhtml', response);
};
```

Reuslt: `<h1>this is html format tag h1</h1>`

I wish:

## this is html format tag h1

This's my view Formhtml:

```
{{pageInfo.content}}
```

What do i do it ? Thanks

Comment: See: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: `{{pageInfo.content|safe}}`, maybe

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but it error. Error: Parse error on line 8:
...<body> {{pageInfo.content|safe}} </bo
---------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

Comment: I use code: {{{pageInfo.content}}}. Thanks All